# Scrapy : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath' in Python webscraping

Tags: python, scrapy

[Snip of my output!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALSwN.jpg) I am getting this error and i can't solve it . Here is my code :

```
import scrapy
class torrentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'torrent'
    start_urls = ['https://www.1337x.to/series-library/b/1/']
    page_number = 2

def parse(self,response):
    href = response.xpath('.//div[@class="movie-info"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
    for urls in href:
        yield {"Linkss" : "https://1337x.to" + urls}
    for alphabets in list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))):
        alpha_url = f'https://www.1337x.to/series-library/{alphabets}/1/'
        last_page = alpha_url.xpath('.//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li/a/text()')[-2].extract() 
        for numbers in str(self.page_number):
            next_page = "https://www.1337x.to/series-library/" + alphabets + "/" + str(numbers)+"/"
            if self.page_number <= int(last_page) :
                self.page_number += 1
                yield response.follow(next_page,callback=self.parse,dont_filter = True  )
```

I have already tried to delete extract from "last_page = alpha_url.xpath('.//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li/a/text()')[-2].extract()"

But it does not work . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace with the corresponding lines please ?

Comment: I have added a link to my snip of  the output , i hope this will be enough? @NoeXWolf

Comment: I'm sure that this is because , the string does not have an attribute Xpath. But I don't know how can i do this any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
    alpha_url = f'https://www.1337x.to/series-library/{alphabets}/1/'
    last_page = alpha_url.xpath(...)...
```

You specifically set `alpha_url` to be a string.  On the next line, you try to call a method that strings do not have.

You have to fetch the html-formatted page information -- as you did above with `response` -- and use `xpath` on *that*.  `xpath` cannot operate on the URL string variable.

Comment: Thank you If you would correct my code with what u just explained , I will be extremely thankful to you . Sorry i don't have much experience with python !